# Disable iOS 11 large title "snapping"

Tags: ios, uikit, ios11

When large titles are enabled on iOS 11 and you scroll down or up and the title changes from large to inline (`automatic`), there is a "snapping" that you can feel.

The contacts app also has large titles, but it doesn't "snap" automatically.

How can I turn this behavior off?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're asking for because I had a similar issue, perhaps you could provide a screen recording just to be sure?

I faced this issue when setting a custom `barTintColor`, in my case `.white` which would cause the effect that I think you're describing.

I fixed this by making my bar translucent and setting the tint to 
`UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 0.99)`.

Hope that helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I've found there are a few things that can cause this:

- The `UIScrollView` (table view, collection view, etc) top is pinned to the safe area. It should be pinned to its superview instead.
- The nav bar is opaque but the VC's `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` is false. This can be set in the storyboard or in code.
- The VC's `edgesForExtendedLayout` doesn't include the top bar. It needs to.